# How to bring up eth0 in Metasploitable virtual machine?

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet

I have installed metasploitable on a virtual machine using vcenter. I had set it up and was trying to configure a static IP address to ethernet interface.
When running ifconfig, there was no eth0 interface and only loopback interface appear.
However, Here's my /etc/network/interfaces :

```
iface lo inet loopback
# primary network interfaces
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

When I'm running ifup eth0, an error message say that :

```
eth0 : ERROR while getting interface flags : No such device
Bind socket to interface : no such device
Failed to bring up eth0
```

I had tried  also

```
ip link set dev eth0 up
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 up
```

and restart every time the network service but I get the same error.
I had tried  also  to set a static IP address to eth0 and restart also the network service but it still the same problem always.
Apparently, my machine does not have eth0 at all are there any other ways to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Hyper-V deploys the VMs with their current network adapter. Being such an old VM, Metasploitable requires legacy hardware.

1. Shutdown the Metasploitable VM.
2. Modify the VM settings
3. Remove any existing network adapters
4. Click "Add Hardware" at the top
5. Choose "Legacy Network Adapter" and click Add
6. Boot the VM.

Now you'll see eth0 on boot, and you can assign a static IP as expected.